# React infinite slideshow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slideshow, setinterval

I'm trying to create infinite slideshow in React. There are a lot of packages that help developers to create slideshow but I would like to do it myself.

Here is the code I tried:

```
    changeImage() {
    this.props.adverts.advertImages.map((img,i) => {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({bg: img.imgSrc})
    }, 3000*(i+1));
    });
  }
```

I'm calling this in returning div like this `{this.changeImage()}`

On the element I have `style={{backgroundImage: "url("+this.state.bg+")"}}`

At start it's slow, few moments later it's to fast..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. What happens is your loop runs and creates an instance of x setInterval (based of the length of the array) thereby you have an array.length amount of setIntervals running which isn't good.

What you want to do is the following:

You want to display an image after a certain amount of time passes (3s)

```
    let index = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        bg: this.props.adverts.advertImages[index++].imgSrc
      })
      if (index === this.props.adverts.advertImages.length) index = 0;
    }, 3000);
```

If you want to add extra logic, say increase the timer interval (make the animation slower) after each tick then you can add indexes to the 3000

The main problem here was that the OP was calling the function inside the render instead of just calling it upon rendering

```
componentDidMount(){
 let index = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        bg: this.props.adverts.advertImages[index++].imgSrc
      })
      if (index === this.props.adverts.advertImages.length) index = 0
    }, 3000);
}

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <Advertisement 
      style={{ backgroundImage: "url("+this.state.bg+")" }} centered unit='billboard' test='Billboard' />
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but with weird behaviour, it shows first image, then wait for three seconds, it shows second but it returns to first in less than it should..

Comment: Could you post an example of your code somewhere online? Like sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: @merko I solved it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sshop-2jda9k?file=components/LandingPage.js  Is it OK now?

Comment: Thank you so much :) Mogli smo i na ovim balkanskim jezicima hehe, sad vidim Varaždin..

Answer (score 0):

Inject this pacakge directly `npm i react-infinite-image-link-carousel`

For reference on this react package [react-infinite-image-link-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-image-link-carousel)